# Bare metal programming on beaglebone black

Tags: beagleboneblack, bare-metal

I have got a beaglebone black and I want to start working on a project from scratch. I have setup the flyswatter2 for debugging and flashing purposes.

I can have a startupcode which ideally should work. but the problem is that I dont know from what memory address the begalebone black starts booting? and what memory address I should flash my code to inside the board's memory?

If I know the place from where I should flash my startup code then from there I can take it up with help of debugger and programming a UART for progress of my code. But I am stuck at the very first step.

Please note that I have read the chaper 26 of technical reference manual for AM335x from ARM and it talks about public RAM and ROM at certain addresses. But I am still unsure about from where to start.

If someone could just let me know that flashing my code at address 0xXXXXXXX will execute my code at startup then I can take it from there.

Thanks in advance
-Ravi

Answer (score 1):

Actually Beaglebone black boards are configured to boot with either external SD cards or an internal eMMC memory, that de-facto is a MMC card soldered in the PCB.

If you take a look to the [documentation](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/spruh73) of the processor on chapter 26 it describes the boot process, from all this section of the documentation, you will be interested for BBB on chapter 26.1.5.7.6. The most simple way is to  format the MMC (or internal eMMC) in FAT format, and right after format create a file called "MLO". It is very important that this file is the very first in the FAT filesystem, so make sure to copy the file right after formatting.

That file is a a small header followed by your application in binary format. The header have the following format (from chapter 26.1.9.2 in same document):

- At offset 0, a 4 bytes word with the size of the image.
- At offset 4, a 4 bytes word with the load address of your image.

Then just your image.

There is a ROM code inside the Sitara processor that "understands" that file and performs the load of the code.

Not a simple procedure for bare-metal, but ....

Hope it helps.